# How do I show a user's current position on a Google Map with a KML layer via a button?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, maps, kml

I'm able to show a trail I plotted as a KML layer on a Google Map, but I would like to show the user their location on the trail when they push a button.  Here's what I have in regards to showing the KML layer.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }

        </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCvtEfhi11SeoL1Osfo8St53JRkasYnTRw&sensor=true">
        </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/bbt.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.183244, -115.585399),
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                                          mapOptions);
            var kmlUrl = 'http://www.sites.google.com/site/skyrokml/kml/FenlandTrail.kml';
            var kmlOptions = {
                suppressInfoWindows: false,
                preserveViewport: true,
                map: map
            };
            var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, kmlOptions);
            if(navigator.geolocation) {
                browserSupportFlag = true;
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                                                         initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
                                                         contentString = "Here you are!";
                                                         map.setCenter(initialLocation);
                                                         infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                                                         infowindow.setPosition(initialLocation);
                                                         infowindow.open(map);
                                                         }, function() {
                                                         handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
                                                         });
            } else if (google.gears) {
                // Try Google Gears Geolocation
                browserSupportFlag = true;
                var geo = google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');
                geo.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                                       initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude);
                                       contentString = "";
                                       map.setCenter(initialLocation);
                                       infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                                       infowindow.setPosition(initialLocation);
                                       infowindow.open(map);
                                       }, function() {
                                       handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
                                       });
            } else {
                // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                browserSupportFlag = false;
                handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
            }
        }

        function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
            if (errorFlag == true) {
                initialLocation = newyork;
                contentString = "Error: The Geolocation service failed.";
            } else {
                initialLocation = siberia;
                contentString = "Error: Your browser doesn't support geolocation. Are you in Siberia?";
            }
            map.setCenter(initialLocation);
            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
            infowindow.setPosition(initialLocation);
            infowindow.open(map);
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="none">
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>
        <ul id="menu" class="blue">
            <li><a href="../../bbteasy/bbteasyfenlandloop.html" rel="external">Back</a></li>
            <li><a href="../../index.html">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How do you expect to get the current location of the user?

Comment: I found an example, but it uses google gears to show an infowindow at the user's location.  This example also centers on the user's location.  What I can't figure out now is (1.) How to sub in a marker for the Google Gears infowindow and (2.) either have the map expanded to show the KML trail layer AND location, or I'll be happy also with just centering on the KML trail layer.  I've shown the new code above.

Comment: Sorry if these questions seem a bit novice, but such is the case.  I managed to center on the KML layer by eliminating the preserveViewport:true.  Still haven't figured out how to show a marker.

Comment: Where do you want the marker to appear?  To put one at the center of the map: `var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.183244, -115.585399), map: map});` should work inside your initialize function. See the [documentation on Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers).

Comment: I really appreciate you taking this up.  My end goal is to show a bike trail (KML layer) and to have the user be able to show their position on the trail.  Ideally I'd like to have the the map centered on the KML layer on the initial load, but with a button click (I still have to add the button) have the map center on their location with a marker.  I know I have a ways to go on this, but any more input would be great.  I'll have a go playing with your previous comment tomorrow.  Your help is golden.  Cheers!

Comment: I did place your marker code between the "var map" and "var kmlurl" and got the marker centered in the middle of the trail (KML layer).  I messed around a bit, but could not get the marker to show for my position and in most attempts the KML layer wouldn't show either.  I have to go to bed.  The morning it is.